# Maclaurin substitution

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I want to to write $f(x)=exp(1-2x^2)$ as a Maclaurin series of order 4 and I know the Maclaurin formula for $exp(x)$.

Can can do this with substitution or do I have to to differentiate $f(x)$ four times?

Comment: $f(x)=e^1\cdot e^{-2x^2}=e\cdot e^{-2x^2}$, so now use what you know about $e^x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$e^X=1+X+\frac{X^2}{2}+o(X^2)$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(1-2x^2)=1\ne 0$$
So, we cannot replace $ X $ by $ 1-2x^2$.

But $e^{-2x^2}=1-2x^2+\dfrac{(-2x^2)^2}{2}+o(x^4)=1-2x^2+2x^4+o(x^4)$.